# Intel 9560 driver error. Issue with wifi loosing signal

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, intel, proprietary

In software and drivers I have found a little mark that Intel 9560() is not working, but there still a wifi signal. I think that Kubuntu doesn't properly install Intel Chipset 9560 and use his open source driver.

I have downloaded from Intel () and do every step in instruction, but problem not solved.

Sometimes wifi signal loses and it's not only one bug in Kubuntu. I have noticed that touch bar sometimes switching off and I use mouse (I have installed Nvidia 440.64 prime driver and it works). In Ubuntu I have been 1 year and one day ago I install Kubuntu.

Touchbar issue is not so terrible, but wifi losing signal 5 ghz is annoying.